# Get contents of Google Drive folder in JSON without login

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

I need to get the contents of a folder in Google Drive without any prompting the user for any authentication. The folder is mine and it's completely public. I have an OAuth2 client ID and an API key.

I don't think that OAuth is the way to go. With OAuth, the current user needs to identify as themselves. That's not what I want at all.

So it'll have to be the API key. I can open this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[folder ID]?key=[my key]
```

And that gives me information about the folder. But if I try this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/[folder ID]/children?key=[my key]
```

I get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
```

I looked this up a lot, but most solution are for per-user content. Here, what I want, is the listing of the one directory and then eventually, access to files inside of it. All of it is public.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say "With OAuth, the current user needs to identify as themselves". This isn't true. It's the most common case, and is the one that most of the examples illustrate, but it's also possible to use any Google Account, or the more specific (and often misunderstood) Service Account.

Comment: After looking more, I found out about the service account. None of the basic examples made it clear that it existed, though.

Comment: Cool. Just be careful that you understand that a Service Account is *not* some proxy for your own account. It's a completely new account.

Comment: You should clarify that you want to do this server side

Answer (score 2):

You are doing wrong here u need to give a file-id as well,which content you want to fetch .Something like this:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B2NqFQc4CTl6Tk1PMTlaaEZFYkk?id={api-key}.
You can get your file-id by clicking on the folder and open in new tab.'
[image]

Comment: that doesn't list the files, just the folder environment, you will need to add /children calling it like this and this will result in a error 401

Answer (score 1):

This was what I was looking for: [the OAuth2 Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

Comment: Do you know if it's safe to make this API call from the front-end, like through Javascript and cross-domain AJAX? For that to occur it would require Google servers to return the correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, and may also expose your service's API key (to those who view the request in dev tools), but if it's permissions are set to read-only, maybe that's not a huge issue.